# ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH" LINE 2: WITH RECURSIVE cte AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Kindly let me know where I am making mistake as i am unable to create procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dpk_mc_tr.dpr_mc_tr_cmo_med_form_arc_inf ( in_usercode text, in_usersess text, in_compcode text, in_stardate text, in_stopdate text, in_sericate text, in_matccate text, in_seritycd text, in_matycode text, in_venucode text, in_teamcode text, in_drsmflag text, in_daynight text, in_telecast text, in_progname text, out_code INOUT numeric ) AS $body$
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
DECLARE

      c01 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_sericate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) sericate

              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_sericate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL  UNION ALL
DECLARE

      c01 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_sericate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) sericate
                    
              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_sericate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL JOIN cte c ON ()

) SELECT * FROM cte;
;

      m01 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT sysofcde sericate
           FROM sycodmas
          WHERE compcode = '001' AND modlcode = 'MM' AND syhrdcde = 'SRC'

UNION ALL

         SELECT 'X' sericate
;WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (


      c02 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_matccate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) matccate

              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_matccate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL  UNION ALL


      c02 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_matccate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) matccate
                    
              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_matccate, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL JOIN cte c ON ()

) SELECT * FROM cte;
;

      m02 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT sysofcde matccate
           FROM sycodmas
          WHERE compcode = '001' AND modlcode = 'MM' AND syhrdcde = 'MAC'

UNION ALL

         SELECT 'X' matccate
;WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (


      c03 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_seritycd, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) seritycd

              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_seritycd, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL  UNION ALL


      c03 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_seritycd, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL
                                                      - 1)),
                                       2,
                                       6
                                      ),
                               ']',
                               ''
                              ) seritycd
                    
              (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(in_seritycd, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1)) IS NOT NULL JOIN cte c ON ()

) SELECT * FROM cte;
;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
> LINE 2: WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query has actually several errors.

1. semicolon in: SELECT 'X' sericate ;WITH ...
2. You cannot use cursors inside a recursive CTE
   Recursive CTE's are actually quite limited. You cannot outer join with cte inside recursive part, you cannot use grouping clause, cannot use cte's name inside a subquery...

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but using with recursive is not a good way to go here... Also, remember that regexp matching is very slow...